# Class incorrectly extends base class static side of "property"

Tags: typescript, oop, swagger-codegen

I got this code from a swagger code generator.

```
class TestClass {
    'type': TestClass.TypeEnum
}

namespace TestClass {
    export enum TypeEnum {
        PERMANENT = <any>'PERMANENT',
        SIMPLE = <any>'SIMPLE'
    }
}

class ExtendedTestClass extends TestClass {
    'type': ExtendedTestClass.TypeEnum
}

namespace ExtendedTestClass {
    export enum TypeEnum {
        SIMPLE = <any>'SIMPLE'
    }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Class static side 'typeof ExtendedTestClass' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof TestClass'.
  Types of property 'TypeEnum' are incompatible.
    Property 'PERMANENT' is missing in type 'typeof ExtendedTestClass.TypeEnum' but required in type 'typeof TestClass.TypeEnum'.ts(2417)
```

I really don't want to edit the generated code, but if it would work I might.

Comment: You may as well open an issue on their GitHub repository about this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review the guidelines for [ask] and consider [edit]ing the post so it asks a well-defined question.  Right now it's not clear what you want us to do; all I know is that you'd prefer not to edit the generated code.  What options are available to you? Do we need to see the input that generated this so it's a [mre]?[mre].